# Handlebars table ie8

Tags: jquery, ajax, handlebars.js

I has a problem with my Handlebars table in IE8, some rows create a blank cell more and destroy de table template. I used ajax and json for to fill the data.

[image]

May you help me ?
Thanks in advance.

> Blockquote

```
 var template = Handlebars.compile(templateOficinas);
 $("[data-result]").css("display","block");
 $("#bodyTableOficina").html(template(result));
```

> Blockquote

```
  <tbody id="bodyTableOficina">
   <script id="template-oficinas" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
      {{#each oficinas}}
      <tr>
      <td>{{nomeFantasia}} 
      <span><i id="iconCategoria" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right"></i></span>
      <span class="status" id="status" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right"></span>
      </td>
      <td>{{numCpfCgc}}</td>
      <td>{{bandeira}}</td>
      <td>{{tipo}}</td>
      <td>{{endereco}}, {{numeroEndereco}}</td>
      <td>{{#if complemento}}{{complemento}}{{else}}<p>-</p>{{/if}}</td>
      <td>{{cep}}</td>
      <td>{{#if bairro}}{{bairro}}{{else}}<p>-</p>{{/if}}</td>
      <td>{{cidade}}</td>
      <td>{{estadoUf}}</td>
      <td>{{#if ddd}}({{ddd}}){{/if}}{{telefone1}}{{#if                  telefone2}}/{{telefone2}}{{/if}}</td>
      </tr>
      {{else}}
      <tr class="tabela-fundo">
      <td colspan="12">Nenhum resultado encontrado</td>
      </tr>
      {{/each}}

   </script>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Do you check in another browsers?

Comment: Yes, in other browser work fine.